# why is the browser shows me file not found error when i try to link javascript file to html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

i have an empty `<p>` tag that i want to change it's text when i click the sumbit button :

```
<div class="error">
    <p id='error'></p>
</div>
```

here is how i am linking the html file to the javascript file :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='sign-up.js'></script>
```

this is the javascript code :

```
function signup(){
document.getElementById('error').value = "This website is'nt finished yet, You can't signup";
};
```

here is the button that should do the task :

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="CREATE ACCOUNT" onclick="signup()">
```

but the problem is when i click the button the browser is showing me this error :

```
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

and it says maybe the file was moved.
so what's the solution ?
note(I am running all the file on the same directory of my computer)

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src='./sign-up.js'></script>` ? and `document.getElementById('error').innerText = "This website is'nt finished yet, You can't signup";` ?

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after your JavaScript runs the form is submitted (you **did** click a submit button) to the URL specified in the `action` attribute of the `<form>`.

It doesn't exist, so the browser is displaying an error instead.

---

Following the principles of [progressive enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) you should be building out the server-side handling of the form at that URL *first*.

Then you can look at [preventing the default behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) of clicking the submit button.

---

If there will never be any server-side handling, then it doesn't make sense to use a submit button in the first place. You should use `type="button"` instead (and can remove the `action` while you are at it.)

---

Aside, once you have that sorted you can address the issues with your JS.

You are trying to set the value of a paragraph. Paragraphs do not have values, only form controls (like inputs) do.

You probably want to set [the `textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using   tags, why not just integrate the JavaScript into the actual program. Just whack it in between those tags, and it should work like a charm. Otherwise, try typing the whole path after "src=". this will work generally, as long as you do not move the JavaScript file from where you have it saved.
this will look like `<script type="text/javascript" src='C:\User\ (navigate through your files and folders to get to sign-up.js)'></script>`
This method is only a stopgap solution though; putting the JavaScript in between the  tags is the best solution.

Comment: I am not downgrading your answer but you should really elaborate your suggestion a little deeper and explain why "that" is the best solution

Comment: I trying what you said i include the javascript script code between the tag but i am the exact same problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
*clear the cookies and try running in a different browser.*
-hopefully it should work
```

- Remove the Duplicate Tab Extension
- Disable Chrome Extensions
- Reset Google Chrome
- Fixing the ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND Error When Developing Extensions

Comment: I am not downgrading this answer but you should elaborate your response a little bit more and provide answers to the specific problem at hand

Comment: why don't you simply write the js code in the index file.

Answer (score -1):

Try to link them like this

```
<script src="sign-up.js"></script>
```

and your function to rewrite like this

```
function signup(){
    let errorMessage = 'This website isnt finished yet, You cant signup';
   let error = document.getElementById('error') ;
   error.textContent = errorMessage;
    };
```

it's tested and working